# Is Gnome too much important for ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I am a new ubuntu user, I installed gnome yesterday, and faced some issues such as :couldn't change my desktop wallpaper, couldn't right click on desktop, all desktop icons became hidden.
As i say before i know very little about ubuntu, and i dont know what job gnome actually does!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME . I don't think there are supposed to be desktop icons on gnome.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: my question is, how important the gnome is?

Comment: The intent of your question is unclear.

Comment: As you can remove it and replace it by something else - it isn't a critical component. I hope that helps you  ... while i am still struggling with the 'question'  ;)

Comment: What did you have before Gnome?   You may need to revert to whatever you were using....

Answer (score 1):

Gnome is a desktop environment typically consists of icons, windows, toolbars, wallpapers , desktop widgets ...

It's important to have at least one desktop environment installed but Gnome is not the only choice.

You can remove gnome and install one of [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Gallery). for details about desktop environments and how to install them look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available).

Comment: You don't need a desktop environment if a terminal is enough for you.